# CSS border attribute adds several layers for borders

Tags: html, css, border

I am getting started on a simple web page but I can't get around this issue.
When I run this simple Script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Test</title>
    <style>
      div {
        border: 5px solid blue;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>this is an element</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I get the following unexpected output: [image: image of div with multiple layers of the bottom border]

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

What I got
please put

the class on div and add CSS style to it.

it will affect a specific class, not whole divs.

```css
.div-element{
        border: 5px solid blue;
      }
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="div-element">this is an element</div>
  </body>
```

Comment: Well, I tried to open the file with Safari as opposed to Chrome and it worked. Is there some sort of Chrome setting in play here?

Comment: check now updated code please this will help you more

Comment: Aha now it works. I'm just confused, because there aren't any objects that inherit from the div or anything. And besides, the first code worked on Safari normally.